# Python, Pandas, Sqlalchemy: using values in input() within query

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have created a script to extract data from db and output to piped text file. However, now I want to have the user provide the ids and then use the user input within the query for IN like

```
engine1 = create_engine()
ids=input("Enter the IDs needed for file generation: ")
print("extracting the data for ", ids)
stext=text("SELECT * FROM table WHERE data IN ids")
data1 = pd.read_sql(stext, con=engine1)
data1.to_csv('new.txt',sep='|',encoding='utf8',index=False,line_terminator='||\n')
```

**ids would be a query list like  ('id1',id2','id3')**

Comment: you don't need to make data1 a dataframe again.  it's a dataframe when it comes out of read_sql.

Comment: ok, corrected that to remove the redundant - how about an answer to the actual pressing question :)

Comment: what database are you using?  it's the most important part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The paramaters syntax will differ based on your DB but your SQL would need to look something like this.

SQL

```
ids=input(SELECT * FROM table WHERE data IN (:ids))


   -- without knowing your DB this is psuedo code.  
   -- In postgres you might be able to use ANY(ARRAY) and use native postgres any python arrays
```

The python code would be something like

```
data1 = pandas.read_sql_query(
                            sa.text(ids),
                            con=conn,
                            params={ 
                                'ids'  : [1,2,3,4,5]
                            }
                      )
```

...also
read_sql returns a dataframe

```
data1 = pd.read_sql(stext, con=engine1)


data1.to_csv('new.txt',sep='|',encoding='utf8',index=False,line_terminator='||\n')
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: @Kosch-sorry about that I thought I put in there - I am using cx_Oracle to connect to oracle exadata like engine1 = create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle:.............

Comment: Also, I would not know how many values for the ids the user would give--it could be 1 or 5 or 100 etc..

Answer (score 0):

I have solved half the issue here is the code, but running into issue where if I give more than one value for input, it does not return the result, giving 1 id is working in this code

```
def extractPcFile():
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x)
dsn = "oracle+cx_oracle://)))"
engine = create_engine(dsn)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
connection = engine.connect()
session = session(bind=connection)
metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base()
hcids=input("Enter the HCIDs needed for PC file generation:")
print("extracting the data for ", hcids)
sql = ("select * from table where HCID in (:hcids)")
result=engine.execute(sql, hcids,).fetchall()
print(result)
extractPcFile()
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: As you continue to make progress toward a solution, edit the original question with updates and clarifications so that contributors can find the most recent question